# ASP.NET MVC 5 Angular IE 9 - Changing to compatibility View crash the browser

Tags: jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer, model-view-controller

I got this site that it is using MVC 5, Api 2 with angular and Jquery, etc. Weird thing it is happening when I deployed it to an intranet server, since it is intranet an internal policy will force any site to be under compatibility view then deep linking into angular will falled in a loop trying to get the scripts bundles many times till IE runs out of memory an dies.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know which version of IE it is setting the compatibility view back to? It could be that it is forcing it into IE7 or possibly even IE8. I ran into similar issue recently with a different JavaScript library and I had to manually override the compatibility view settings in the web.config file. To do this, you need to add a tag to the `<customHeaders>` node of the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
           <httpProtocol> 
               <customHeaders> 
                    <clear /> 
                    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9" /> 
               </customHeaders> 
           </httpProtocol> 
     </system.webServer> 
  </configuration>
```

The `<add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9" />` is the part that you need to add. This will force the compatibility view to use a newer version of the IE emulation, in this case it is setting it to use IE9.

Here is some more info from [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deviations/archive/2009/05/07/how-to-enable-ie-8-compatibility-view-for-your-whole-web-site-or-for-specific-web-site-directories.aspx).

Comment: Also you need to verify your angular version. 1.3+ does not support IE8 and below anymore officially.

Comment: That is a very good point. There is also some good info on the Angular site if you NEED to support IE8 or below: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: @JoshTaylor I am using IE9 I am also doing the X-UA-Compatible to IE=9, the problem with this is that, this will change the document view but not the browser view that is set to compatibility view.

Comment: @Tacoman667 I am using version 1.2.16, also test it with 1.2.18 and 1.2.10 and made no different

Comment: Compatibility mode is one of MS's worst ideas. It is nothing but pain. I HIGHLY suggest to not use it and try to disable it in your html whenever possible.

Comment: I do agree with you really bad idea, but it is not possible to disable it from code, user have to do it manually

Comment: I forgot to mention, you can force the IE to use whatever the most current rendering engine is by using <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EDGE" /> . This will help you to take advantage of all the available features supported by your current IE browser version.